# my webview(and any views) overlap my sidebar in only one scenario iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, view

I'm implementing this side bar in my project : https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu
and so far so good in my first view controller:
[image]

but in a second view controller my sidebar is behind any view! and I implemented the sidebar in the same way.

[image]

So then I tried the following functions but nothing changes : /

```
    originView.bringSubviewToFront(sideBarConteinerView)
```

I use originView because I create my sidebar view in another class

I also tried the below function on the views that are overlapping my sidebar but I get the same results.

```
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(webview)
```

I also tried using the two functions at the same time, could you help me with some ideas of how can I overcome this situation? I really appreciate your help.

update:

VIEW1 (OK): 
[image]

View2 (sidebar get overlapped):
[image]

update 2:

Just when I tough that the problem was gone (see my below answer) I found that when I go back from VC2 to the main VC1 my VC1 had two sidebars! and then if I go to the VC2 again my VC2 had 3 sidebars! and so on! so I deleted the self.navigationController!.view and change it again to self.view to pass it to my sidebar class and this error doesn't exist anymore but again my other views overlapped my sidebar in my VC2 but in VC1 no : (.

screenshot update 2:
[image]

Comment: What is the desired outcome? or what exactly do you want to change?

Comment: Can you describe the structure of your app? Is your side bar just a view in a VC? And is the WebView in the same VC or is it being swapped in as a child VC?

Comment: @Nick I want the same results of my first VC, I want my sidebar to be above all the views in my VC. as you can see in my second screen all the views are above my sidebar and I don't want that.

Comment: @MikeCole I have two VC (VC1 & VC2), and two swift classes to make my sidebar (a tableviewcontroller.swift and a Sidebar.swift) in each of my two VC I implement a SideBarDelegate and I only pass the source view and data to my Sidebar instance to make my sidebar apear ( sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: tableNSDictionary)) So... in my VC1 all works just fine, my sidebar is above all the child views of my VC1, But in my VC2 any view is above my sidebar and I don't know why. By the way.. I made my two VC screens in the storyboard and as you know, my sidebar view code.

Comment: Is there a placeholder view for your sidebar in each VC? Or is that view added programmatically to each VC via the delegate?

Comment: my sidebar is added programmatically via the delegate like you said @MikeCole

Comment: I made an update of my post showing the structure of the views

Comment: Still a problem! see my post Update, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sideMenuContainerView is probably inside UINavigationController view. You need to call
`self.navigationController.view.bringSubviewToFront(sideMenuContainerView)`

Comment: I use the following function in the screen that doesn't work and still doesn't work self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sideBar.sideBarConteinerView) But I notice that you put self and then navigationController but the navegationController is not the self itself?

Comment: I finally manage to solve the error with your help, but I don't know exactly what I did, well I will post the answer and give you a +1,Thank you so much, if you have a chance please see the answer and  comment it

Comment: try to run this code in viewWillAppear on every view controller

Comment: I finally get it right! but I put it in the viewDidAppear function!, I still have the curiosity to know why in my first view controller I didn't have to bring the subview to the front : /

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get the results I want passing the origin view in another way to my sidebar class **like this :**
           sideBar = SideBar(sourceView:  self.navigationController!.view, menuItems: tableNSDictionary)

**Instead of this:** 
           sideBar = SideBar(sourceView:  self.view, menuItems: tableNSDictionary)

I don't know the difference between self.view and self.navigationController!.view (someone could tell me? to fully understand) but anyway the strange part is that in my first VC it doesn't matter if I put self.view or self.navigationController!.view D:!! I get the same good result for my sidebar, but in my second VC I need to pass the view to my sidebar class  like this : self.navigationController!.view .

Comment: I finally get it right! but I put my bringSubviewToFront function in the viewDidAppear function!, I still have the curiosity to know why in my first view controller I didn't have to bring the subview to the front : /